# postcss-loader error during tailwind upgrade from 0.7.0 to 1.x

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

In order to upgrade my tailwind version from 0.7.0 to 1.x(1.9.6), I followed the [tailwind official documentation](https://v1.tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrading-to-v1#1-update-tailwind).

While building, I received this error despite following the instructions in the [docs](https://v1.tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrading-to-v1#1-update-tailwind)

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                      19:10:26
This dependency was not found:
* -!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--7-oneOf-3-1!../../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--7-oneOf-3-2!tailwindcss/preflight.css in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--7-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--7-oneOf-3-2!./src/assets/css/tailwind.postcss
To install it, you can run: npm install --save -!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--7-oneOf-3-1!../../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--7-oneOf-3-2!tailwindcss/preflight.css
```

Some basic details:

```
Technology stack used: Vue.js & tailwind
node version: 14.8.1
npm version: 8.3.0
nodejs version: 8.10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the above issue by following these steps

```
 1. open tailwind.postcss file
 2. Replace @import "~tailwindcss/preflight.css"; with @import "~tailwindcss/base.css";
```

From [here](https://v1.tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrading-to-v1#4-replace-tailwind-preflight-with-tailwind-base) I got a hint about a solution, Thanks!!